# QR code for Android messages not loading in Firefox

Tags: firefox, qr-code

When I visit Google web messages (messages.google.com/web) in Firefox, the QR code does not load (see image below).

I have tried the following:

- opening Firefox in safe-mode
- disabling AdBlocker and Add-ons
- adjusting cookie, history, etc. settings
- modifying the following about: config settings

  - privacy.resistFingerprinting = false
  - network.http.spdy.websockets=false

Interestingly, the QR code loads in Firefox for WhatsApp but not Android messages.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What is the version of Firefox and the name and version of the Operative System that you are using? Have you already tried on another computer?

Comment: Seeing the same with Firefox 73. Google anti-competitive behavior at its best.